# Android: Unable to start activity: NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am trying to open a `New Activity` within my application using an `intent` once a game on the previous activity is finished, like shown below. I am getting a `NullPointerException`, What am I doing wrong?

**Code to open new activity:**

```
//when no cards are left
                if(totalcards==0){

                    //get the avg med and att values
                    getAverageMeditationValue();
                    getAverageAttentionValue();

                    if(getAverageMeditationValue() && getAverageAttentionValue()){

                    //add session detail to the SQLite DB
                    writeToDatabase();
                    //intent to open activty showing results of session
                    Intent t = new Intent(MemoryGame.this, com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults.class);
                    t.putExtra("singleScore", single);
                    // Start intent
                    startActivity(t);
                    //stop recording EEG data
                    device.close();
                    }
                }
```

**New activity:**

```
 public class MemoryGameResults extends Activity {
    //declare vars
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView tv3;
    TextView tv4;
    TextView tv5;
    TextView tv6;
    Session singleScore;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.memorygameresults);

        initialiseVars();

        setUpAllTextViews();


    }

    public void initialiseVars() {

        // the single score from the the meditation class
        singleScore = (Session) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
                "singleScore");

        // Declaring textViews
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults4);
        tv5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults5);
        tv6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults6);

    }

    /**
     * Sets text for all textviews
     * in activity
     */
    public void setUpAllTextViews(){

        // setting text for each text view
        tv1.setText("Results of session:");
        tv2.setText("Average Meditation Value: " + singleScore.getMeditation());
        tv3.setText("Maximum Meditation Value: " + singleScore.getMax());
        tv4.setText("Average Attention Value: " + singleScore.getAvgAttention());
        tv5.setText("Maximum Attention Value: " + singleScore.getMaxAttention());
        tv6.setText("Correct Answers: " + singleScore.getScore());
    }

    }

/**
 * Method that ensures user is returned to main menu when they press back
 * button
 */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent t = new Intent(MemoryGameResults.this, com.example.brianapp.MainMenu.class);
    startActivity(t);
}
```

}

**When I try to do so I am getting the following error:**

```
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074): Process: com.example.brianapp, PID: 17074
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.brianapp/com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults.setUpAllTextViews(MemoryGameResults.java:323)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults.onCreate(MemoryGameResults.java:51)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):    ... 11 more
```

**Manifest sections relating to the two activities:**

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.MemoryGame"
            android:label="Memory Game" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.brianapp.MemoryGame" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults"
            android:label="Memory Game Results" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**mathsgameresults.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults1"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults2"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults3"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape3"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults4"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape2"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults5"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/medresults6"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonshape3"
        android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </TextView>

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMathsResultsViewgraph"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:onClick="Graph8Handler"
            android:text="View Graph "
            android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post `mathsgameresults.xml`

Comment: Just edited the post showing this, thanks

Comment: is this line 323  `singleScore = (Session) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("singleScore");`??

Comment: No it is: tv1.setText("Results of session:");

Comment: The problem is in `MemoryGameResults`, but you've posted `MathsGameResults`. Also, the line you just listed in your comment does not appear anywhere in the posted code.

Comment: Sorry I have made an edit

Comment: tv1.setText("Results of session:"); is still line 323 in this activity

Comment: @user3968848 tv1 is null indicating problem when you initialize tv1

Comment: @user3968848 your views are in `mathsgameresults.xml` while the layout that you set to the activity is `memorygameresults`. So your initialization fails

Comment: Can I just ask a quick question. In this logcat code: 08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074): at com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults.setUpAllTextViews(MemoryGameResults.java:‌​323) does "323" relate to the line number of the which there is the error?

Comment: as you also having same problem as mine, take a look here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565628/unable-to-start-activity-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in these lines :

```
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medresults2);
    ...
```

The textviews are not being initialized. Check your XML file(`memorygameresults.xml`) whether textviews with these IDs exist.

Comment: Thanks, the issue was as you described. R.id.medresults1 should have been R.id.memresults1. I.e. the "d" and "m" were mixed up resulting in the error.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. :) Would be happy if you accept this as an answer :)

Comment: Accepted, Can I just ask a quick question. In this logcat code:   08-24 10:56:44.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17074):  at com.example.brianapp.MemoryGameResults.setUpAllTextViews(MemoryGameResults.java:323) does "323" relate to the line number of the which there is the error?

Comment: Yes it indicates the line number at which the `Exception` occured

Comment: Thanks for your help. I always have problems with exceptions